# when i close the form dialog and reopen,the form is still red and isn’t initialized。

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i write a form like this with vuetify.

```
   <v-form>
          <v-text-field
            autocomplete="off"
            v-model="model.password"
            :label="formschema.password.label"
            :rules="[rules.required, rules.min]"
            :append-icon="formschema.password.show ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
            @click:append="formschema.password.show = !formschema.password.show"
            :type="formschema.password.show ? 'text' : 'password'"
            required
          ></v-text-field>
          <v-text-field
            autocomplete="off"
            v-model="model.newpassword"
            :label="formschema.newpassword.label"
            :rules="[rules.required, rules.min]"
            :type="formschema.newpassword.show ? 'text' : 'password'"
            :append-icon="
              formschema.newpassword.show ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'
            "
            @click:append="
              formschema.newpassword.show = !formschema.newpassword.show
            "
            required
          ></v-text-field>
          <v-text-field
            autocomplete="off"
            v-model="model.comfirmpassword"
            :label="formschema.comfirmpassword.label"
            :rules="[rules.required, rules.min]"
            :append-icon="
              formschema.comfirmpassword.show ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'
            "
            @click:append="
              formschema.comfirmpassword.show = !formschema.comfirmpassword.show
            "
            :type="formschema.comfirmpassword.show ? 'text' : 'password'"
            required
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-form>
```

when i close it (the form is in an dialog),i clean the data,
but when i reopen it ,it will return errrors:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"
```

please help me .how can i reset the form data but not get the error ?

i clean my form just let the model bind to form's items = default model.
such as:

```
this.model = this.defaultmodel
```

Comment: you can use useState

Comment: You have not provided the part of the code that attempts to read a length property.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about your vue data object and how you clean the form data?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/#validation-with-submit-clear

You have to basically call `this.$refs.form.resetValidation()` after you have closed the dialog.

Comment: thanks. but how can i reset some data but not all of it?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with "some data", you mean only 1 field validation reset or do you want to reset the input data?

Comment: @JasonLanbridge  i want to reset some of field validation and data,but not all of the form's data. such as {username,password} to reset the password but not reset the username to null..

Comment: Well if you would like to reset the password, then you can just `model.comfirmpassword = ''`. This should reset the validation as well.